# Use of "UINavigationBar appearance setTranslucent:NO" in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I am Defining My `UINavigationBar` color code in `AppDelegate` with:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:87.0f/255.0f blue:10.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
```

Then I also set the `Translucent` of my `NavigationBar` with:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

My Project's `Deployment target` is iOS 7 & `Target SKD` iOS 8. The project got crash only when I run it on any iOS 7 device. After digging a little, I found that `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];` is not worked in iOS 7. So I want to know **"Except calling it locally (in every `viewController`)"** is there any way to use it for iOS 7 to iOS8?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a non exist image that makes fool of compiler like:-

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

instead of:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```